# Existing list overwritten when creating a new list

Tags: python, list, python-3.8

In the script below, something strange happens when the second loop starts. The list `area_1` changes value even though it is not involved in that loop at all. Same happens with `area_2` after the third loop.

```
server_1 = 'x1'
server_2 = 'x2'
server_3 = 'x3'
table = [
    {'Terminal': 'site_1', 'City': 'London', 'Station': server_1},
    {'Terminal': 'site_2', 'City': 'London', 'Station': server_1},
    {'Terminal': 'site_3', 'City': 'London', 'Station': server_2},
    {'Terminal': 'site_4', 'City': 'New York', 'Station': server_3},
    {'Terminal': 'site_5', 'City': 'New York', 'Station': server_1},
    {'Terminal': 'site_6', 'City': 'New York','Station': server_2},
    {'Terminal': 'site_7', 'City': 'Tokyo', 'Station': server_3},
    {'Terminal': 'site_8', 'City': 'Tokyo', 'Station': server_3},
    {'Terminal': 'site_9', 'City': 'Tokyo', 'Station': server_2}    
]
city_index = [ 
    {'City':'London', 'Lat': 51.48,'Long': -0.14 },
    {'City':'New York', 'Lat': 40.69,'Long': -74.26 },
    {'City':'Tokyo', 'Lat': 35.51,'Long': 138.64 }
]
area_1 = []
for i in city_index:
    area_1.append(i)
    area_1[-1].update({'Station': server_1, 'Count of terminals': sum(q['City'] == i['City'] and q['Station'] == server_1 for q in table)})
area_2 = []
for i in city_index:
    area_2.append(i)
    area_2[-1].update({'Station': server_2, 'Count of terminals': sum(q['City'] == i['City'] and q['Station'] == server_2 for q in table)})
area_3 = []
for i in city_index:
    area_3.append(i)
    area_3[-1].update({'Station': server_3, 'Count of terminals': sum(q['City'] == i['City'] and q['Station'] == server_3 for q in table)})

all = area_1 + area_2 + area_3

for i in all:
    print(i)
```

Output: (Notice the station key)

```
{'City': 'London', 'Lat': 51.48, 'Long': -0.14, 'Station': 'x3', 'Count of terminals': 0}
{'City': 'New York', 'Lat': 40.69, 'Long': -74.26, 'Station': 'x3', 'Count of terminals': 1}
{'City': 'Tokyo', 'Lat': 35.51, 'Long': 138.64, 'Station': 'x3', 'Count of terminals': 2}
{'City': 'London', 'Lat': 51.48, 'Long': -0.14, 'Station': 'x3', 'Count of terminals': 0}
{'City': 'New York', 'Lat': 40.69, 'Long': -74.26, 'Station': 'x3', 'Count of terminals': 1}
{'City': 'Tokyo', 'Lat': 35.51, 'Long': 138.64, 'Station': 'x3', 'Count of terminals': 2}
{'City': 'London', 'Lat': 51.48, 'Long': -0.14, 'Station': 'x3', 'Count of terminals': 0}
{'City': 'New York', 'Lat': 40.69, 'Long': -74.26, 'Station': 'x3', 'Count of terminals': 1}
{'City': 'Tokyo', 'Lat': 35.51, 'Long': 138.64, 'Station': 'x3', 'Count of terminals': 2}
```

All 3 lists become identical at the end = `area_3`.
Can someone please explain why this is happening? Why are `area_1` and `area_2` being overwritten?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`area_1` and `area_2` are not being overwritten. What's actually being overwritten is `city_index`. Try printing it after everything you do, and you will see.

---

To avoid this, you should copy the contents of `city_index`, instead of overwritting (`dict.update(...)`) them.

One way to do this is to find everywhere you do:

```
area_x.append(i)
```

Change it to

```
area_x.append(dict(**i)) # or area_x.append(dict(i))
```

This will force `i` to be copied rather than referenced.

Comment: @superbrain I guess it doesn't really matter. `dict(i)` works as well

Comment: You are right, `city_index` is being modified, even though my code is not doing any changes on it, it just copies from it. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Skyoxic it's happening because of the `.update()` calls you make. `i` is an element of `city_index` and it is not copied when you add it to the list. So when you do `list[-1].update(...)`, you are actually updating `i` which is inside `city_index`

Comment: thank you, but it's still not very clear to me. The function `.append()` supposedly copies a value and adds it to the list (I tested that in the interpreter by appending a variable to a list, then changing the value of that variable, the list remained unchanged). This was true for a string as an appended list element, but when I tried to reproduce the case with dictionaries, the function `.update()` seems to change the value of both the original dictionary and the appended list element. Was I not able to reproduce it with strings because they are immutable?

Answer (score 5):

Use `copy` module to copy objects istead of refering to them.

```
import copy
area.append(copy.copy(i))
```

Also, using `i` as iterator that is not an integer is very confusing, try to avoid it